# Transparência de um SWF com wmode=transparent não funciona no Firefox

Tags: html, actionscript-3, firefox, flash

Preciso exibir um SWF com transparência. O `<wmode = transparent>` está funcionando em todos os navegadores, menos no Firefox. O que pode ser?

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="root" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="root.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#666" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">          
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
```

Comment: Na verdade, sua pergunta tem um problema porque você não mostra o código completo. O exemplo acima é inválido.

Answer (score 1):

Se usar o [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation), provavelmente vai se livrar desse problema. É a maneira recomendada de inserir objetos Flash no HTML, e é necessária se quiser que o SWF e o JavaScript possam passar informação de um lado para outro. Tem um [gerador de código embed](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html) no site do projeto.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Usando SWFObject</title>
    <style>
        body {background-color:#c00;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Embed normal
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "best";
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("SEU-SWF.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

        // Embed de YouTube
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Embedding
        var yt_params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        var yt_atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "http://www.youtube.com/v/aZMbTFNp4wI?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
            "ytapiplayer", 
            "425", 
            "356", 
            "8", 
            null, 
            null, 
            yt_params, 
            yt_atts
        );            
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myAlternativeContent">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
    </div>
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/LLrzj29u/)

Comment: muito bom @brasofilo

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

em vez de:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Pelo que li ambos tem uma função parecida e pode resolver seu problema.

Comment: Vlw pela dica maninho, mas infelizmente não funcionou :(

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema: bastou eu criar um `<!--[if !IE]>-->` e especificar novamente o `vmode` para `transparent`.

Comment: vmode não wmode certo ?